# Cómo llevar este form html a Laravel Collective?

Tags: laravel

Lo hice en Laravel Collective pero no me respeta la confirmación de la contraseña, siempre dice que no coincidem y están bien, no sé que está mal:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"autocomplete="new-password">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña" autocomplete="new-password">
</div>
```

Laravel Collective:

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
    <label>Contraseña</label>
    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contraseña']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
    <label>Repetir contraseña</label>
    {{ Form::password('password-confirm', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Repetir contraseña']) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba poniéndole el mismo nombre seguido de `_confirmation`, o sea `password_confirmation`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El campo de confirmación debe se `password_confirmation` y no `password-confirm`

Laravel menciona esto en su documentación

> **confirmed**
> The field under validation must have a matching field of **foo_confirmation**. For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching **password_confirmation** field must be present in the input.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-password

Comment: Muchas gracias!